# C++ Input Stream

Tags: c++

I have a program that work with data which is paste to console. For example when the program is run and I paste

```
delete 54545
add 4324
```

the program call delete function with parameter 54545, but wait for enter after 4324 to call second function. And I have no idea how to call it without press enter.

example

first line is how many functions should call. and I paste this at console

```
3
delete 4324324
add 324
add 4324
```

the code is like that

```
...
int count;
string func, parameter;
cin >> count;
for (int i=1; i<=count;i++) {
    cin >> func;
    switch(func) {
       case "add": cin >> parameter; add(parameter); break;
       case "delete": cin >> parameter; delete(parameter); break;
    }
}
...
```

all function is called but the last one is not...
in this example last function is add and the program wait to press enter after

```
case "add": cin >> parameter
```

to call function.

Comment: It smells like you need `ncurses` and/or `getch(e)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to process input supplied by the user and do not want to wait with parsing until the user presses enter, you cannot use standard streams for that.

Insead [getch()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch) function might work for you, please note hovewer that this is not standard C/C++.